# Classic ASP VBScript offline reference

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I don't do a slew of VB in classic ASP, so I'm looking for an offline reference I can use while I'm well...offline. General syntax and ADO goodies are a plus!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have IIS installed, it should be there on your system.

Comment: how do I access it? I took a peek at the help files and there are only a few references to ASP

Comment: aha!

http://localhost/iisHelp

Thanks!

Comment: "Offline reference" - do you mean, "a book"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Script 5.6 documentation includes a reference for both VBScript and JScript, amongst other goodies. You can download the  [offline version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01592C48-207D-4BE1-8A76-1C4099D7BBB9&displaylang=en) from Microsoft's download center.

ADO docs con't come w/ the scripting reference , but I think you can get offline ADO documentation when you download the [MDAC 2.8 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5067faf8-0db4-429a-b502-de4329c8c850&displaylang=en).  Just do a customized install and only pick the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to localhost/iisHelp (does that have developer docs in it?) you can find all you need even in an old version of the MSDN library for VS if you have one lying around.

Answer (score 0):

The best time for this was 2001 or so.  I can't find a lot of reference websites that I depended on for day to day stuff.  Most have moved on to .Net.  MSDN might be the best reference.